# how to use multi-bluetooth from Android studio?

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I want making multi-bluetooth from andorid studio.

I found multi-bluetooth java code libraries, but I am difficult to use. (Because I do not speak English well :'-()

-find site-

https://arissa34.github.io/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/adeBD275u30

I want to make. (from Android studio)

[Fitness game machine 1 & joystick 1 - bluetooth Android phone 1]

Please tell me on a site presented above, helpful site that correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently developed an Android app that aims to make this as simple as possible. The [source](https://github.com/reshaping-the-future/better-together) is available (Apache 2.0) if you're interested.

To develop a game that does what you describe, you'd simply include the [plugin api](https://github.com/reshaping-the-future/better-together-api), which abstracts all of the connectivity and gives you simple send and receive methods to all connected clients.